# How To Add A Text Panel Over An Image In CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently redesigning my blog, and would like to have a panel at the bottom of each image going across at the top of the blog. I have searched the internet and couldn't find exactly what I was looking for.

This is what the image at the top currently looks like

http://i1078.photobucket.com/albums/w483/tobster619/Gaming%20Images/FeaturedImage_zpsf93acced.png

At the bottom of the image I have been trying to get a panel, in CSS, that looks as if it's wrapping around behind the image, like a 3d effect popping out, and then to be able to add text to it.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Can you create a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: This is the best I could do, because all of the code is inside the blogger template - http://jsfiddle.net/DxNpB/

Answer (score 0):

Just put the image and the panel you want in a wrapper div, put `position:relative` on the wrapper so the absolute positioned text is placed relative to the wrapper. `position:absolute` and a `z-index` on the `panel` so that you can position it where you want and have it higher in the z-index order. And finally put a `z-index` on the image that has a lesser value then the `panel` `z-index`

**HTML**

```
<div class="textImgHover">
   <img src="someimage.jpg" />
   <div class="panel">
     <div class="panelitem">Panel Item 1</div>
     <div class="panelitem">Panel Item 2</div>
     <div class="panelitem">Panel Item 3</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.textImgHover {
   position:relative;
}

.textImgHover .panel {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:5px;
   left:5px;
   z-index:20;
}

.textImgHover .panelitem {
   float:left; 
   margin-right:5px;
   background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
   color:#FFF;
   padding:3px;
}

.textImgHover img {
   position:relative;
   z-index:10;
}
```